# AWS own email domain and some generic questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, host

I'm getting started with Amazon Web Services and I have a few question I'm not sure about. As every (company) webpage I want to use an "office@companyname.com" email adress, but how is that done? I looked up at godaddy.com (for domain registration), the offer me an email adress like I want, but for 3 dollars per month.

Is this possible with AWS? Because at AWS you have just a complex domain which is not very userfriendly or serious.

Also I want to host my dynamic webpage on the amazon cloud, but I'm not sure if I'm doing that right. I've read many guides, and all I know is that I have to purchase a Elastic Compute Cloud, and a Simple Storage Service... and every guide is working with the basic linux package, why not Windows? Is it more expensive? I just want to host a mySQL Server for the dynamic webpage, which is reached over a normal domain.

And one last question, if I sign up for an AWS account it asks me for an email account. But I found it a little bit unserious to write there my free-webmailer-adress... How is it done the normal way?

Thanks in advance! Best regards, john.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of non-specific non-technical questions, and you might be better served asking them on one of the Amazon forums (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa?categoryID=1).

Based your implied lack of experience you might be better off starting with a shared hosting service like Godaddy.  Amazon AWS adds a layer of technical complexity that you may not need for your situation...

That said, here are some general answers to you Amazon questions:

- Amazon AWS provides generally comparable hosting services for both Windows and Linux.
- Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) will send bulk email, but it will not receive email.  To do that within the Amazon ecosystem you would need to run your on mail server(s).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know i'm asking like a noob, but these cloud things are totally new for me. I'm missing the big picture, and when i'm missing this i can't understand it. But after reading some theory i come closer to the big picture. For hosting a dynamic webpage there is a ec2 needed (server), a Ebs (for storing data even if the server is down) and amazon route 53 (for human readable web-adresses). Right? Its a little bit a modular concept in my eyes...

Comment: For hosting web apps you should take a look at Elastic beanstalk which insulates you from some of the underlying details...